# How to generate grpc java file in vscode using maven?

Tags: java, grpc

I notice that the official example use a plugin named `os-maven-plugin` which is incompatible with vscode .

Comment: You need to describe the error/problem you see. Just saying "incompatible" isn't helpful.

Comment: If you read the [```os-maven-plugin```'s document](https://github.com/trustin/os-maven-plugin) , you will find this plugin can only be used in ```IDEA``` and ```Eclipse```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `protoc-jar-maven-plugin` instead .

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.os72</groupId>
                <artifactId>protoc-jar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.11.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <protocArtifact>com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.17.3</protocArtifact>
                            <inputDirectories>
                                <include>src/main/proto</include>
                            </inputDirectories>
                            <outputTargets>
                                <outputTarget>
                                    <type>java</type>
                                    <outputDirectory>src/main/java</outputDirectory>
                                </outputTarget>
                                <outputTarget>
                                    <type>grpc-java</type>
                                    <pluginArtifact>io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:1.39.0</pluginArtifact>
                                    <outputDirectory>src/main/java</outputDirectory>
                                </outputTarget>
                            </outputTargets>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Update 20220112

Adding this to maven setting file also works:

```
<profiles>
  <profile>
    <id>os-properties</id>
    <properties>
      <os.detected.name>linux</os.detected.name>
      <os.detected.arch>x86_64</os.detected.arch>
      <os.detected.classifier>linux-x86_64</os.detected.classifier>
    </properties>
  </profile>
</profiles>

<activeProfiles>
  <activeProfile>os-properties</activeProfile>
</activeProfiles>
```

Comment: is that the only plugin that will work with vscode? We build using maven and          org.xolstice.maven.plugins :protobuf-maven-plugin. It works on a maven build from the command line, but the generated sources directories are always empty in vscode.

Comment: Yes , I think it is . I have tried ```org.xolstice.maven.plugins :protobuf-maven-plugin``` , the same as you , it didn't work ...